# Re-use of database with PHPass passwords

Tags: codeigniter, symfony, phpass

Just need a little advice. I have a website based on CodeIgniter and using TankAuth and PHPass. I want to recode the website with another framework (Symfony 2).

Is there any way to allow user to log with their existing password or do I absolutely need to ask them to set a password again ?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Are the passwords already crypted with a salt?

Comment: Yes, they are. Any way to do this ?

Comment: As seen in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html#modify-security-yml), Symfony use sha512 with a salt by default. What method did you use exactly (algorithm, number of iterations, etc.)? There is maybe a way to use the same methods on your previous code and with Symfony2.

Comment: The previous code is from another guy, he used like a weird homemade hashing method :/

Comment: If it's too complicated or impossible to use this method in Symfony2, resetting passwords may be the only solution.

Comment: You're right, I think I am going to do that. Thanks for your advice ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best is to reset all the password and warn users through email or ask them to change the password with the new system.